# DJVU reader from scratch. C#

Tags: c#, djvu

I want to write your own djvu reader in C #. Prompt where to start?

---

Program write in C # (Winforms) in Visual Studio. The problem arises in that I do not understand how to read djvu. Or rather take it apart to import each image for further display in the program.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DjVu is an open standard. There is a C++-based library which reads the format. You can just copy it if you can open source your code (it's GPL): http://djvu.sourceforge.net/.

If not, you can start with the specs at http://djvu.org/resources/ and code up your own from scratch.

Good luck!

Comment: That library is C++ based.

Comment: Feel free to just update the answer next time. With over 2,000 rep you can do that. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You start with `File -> New Project`

Stack overflow isn't a "do it for you" site.

> problem arises in that I do not understand how to read djvu

You've identified the problem.  The solution is then to read up on the format and the spec.

Comment: I do not ask me. I asked where to I start? What to read, so I can read the file and extract images.

Comment: yes, but you asked one of the most vaguest questions ever, with little or no context.  What have you tried? what isn't working?  what environment?  what os?  StackOverflow is not Rent-a-Coder.

Answer (score 4):

I have a C# Djvu reader which is open sourced. You can find it here: https://github.com/Telavian/DjvuNet

**Edit:** My library has been taken over by 4creators at: https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FileStream` class to read the file.

Use the `Bitmap` class (WinForms) or the `WriteableBitmap` class (WPF) to write pixels.

Comment: I thought this format the algorithm. And I can not just draw pictures. If I'm wrong correct.

Comment: I can't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

CamiNova, the company that took over development and maintenance of DjVu from LizardTech makes a .NET SDK available.  I would start there.

https://www.caminova.net/en/downloads/download.aspx?id=17

Answer (score 0):

Telavian wrote:

"I have a C# Djvu reader which is open sourced. You can find it here: https://github.com/Telavian/DjvuNet"

Unfortunately, this project doesn't work fully. Normally the documents having some pages open only. The one-page documents which don't have PageHeader, don't boot. Dear Telavian, look please at this moment. I could send samples of documents which don't open

[sample file](http://f-bit.ru/463573)